# Three.js: extruding a triangle mesh from a flat 3d plane triangle shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js, mesh

Trying to extrude a triangle mesh from a Vector3 triangle.

I'm calling `extrudeSettings` in:

```js
var triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry(extrudeSettings);
```

But it's not extruding. What am I doing wrong here?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fajZ4z2LBeq7jiTZJXLY?p=preview)

Here's the relevant JS:

```
   drawTriangle(
       new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(4, 0, 0),
       new THREE.Vector3(2, 3.4641, 0)
   );

   var extrudeSettings = {
                    steps           : 100,
                    bevelEnabled    : false,
                    extrudePath     : closedSpline
   };

   function drawTriangle (vertex1, vertex2, vertex3) {
      var triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry(extrudeSettings);
      var triangleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000,
      wireframe: true,
      wireframeLinewidth: 1
   });

   var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, triangleMaterial);

   triangleGeometry.vertices = [vertex1, vertex2, vertex3];
   triangleGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

   THREE.GeometryUtils.center(triangleGeometry);

   scene.add(triangle);
```

Comment: All you have to do is copy the examples. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

Comment: I did that, there are not clear solid extrusion examples in there, it's a rather complicated example to extract and extrapolate the info for a simple extrusion from.

Comment: Also see http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes.html.

Comment: Thanks much, I'll take a look.

Comment: Or look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193732/three-js-creating-a-right-triangular-prism

Comment: Thanks @AlmazVildanov , perfect.